# how to get private key of Github Pages auto issued HTTPS certificate

Tags: html, github, ssl-certificate

Github pages custom domain service automatically issue a Let’s Encrypt SSL certificate for https connection. my problem is, how to get the private key of this certificate? is it possible?

if the certificate is obtained by myself, the private key locate in /etc/letsencrypt/live, but github pages seem not support self obtained certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature has been [proposed since May 2018](https://github.blog/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/), and is part of the "[Securing your GitHub Pages site with HTTPS](https://help.github.com/en/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https)"

It is a *server-side* (github.io) feature, which means the private key remains... *private*, on the server.
It should therefore *not* be possible to get it back.